# Getting image url from backend,how to show image in html in angular

Tags: angular, image, view, backend

```js
findvehicleDocumentsImage(owner: string, registrationNumber: string, fileType: string): Observable<any> {
  debugger;
  return this.http.get<any>(AppConstant.FIND_VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_API+'/'+owner+'/'+registrationNumber+'/'+fileType);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get img url in ts file:

```
imageUrl:string;
```

show in html:

```
<img src={{imageUrl}} alt=""/>
```

Comment: it is asking for authentication  login

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve an image and display it you should create a service:

#### Image service

```js
findvehicleDocumentsImage(owner: string, registrationNumber: string, fileType: string): Observable { 
  // debugger; 
  return http.get(`${AppConstant.FIND_VEHICLE_DOCUMENT_API}/${owner}/${registrationNumber}/${fileType}`,
    {
      header: {
        authentication: `Bearer ${yourToken}`
      }
    }
  );
}
```

#### Component A - TS

Then in your component, you have to call the method and render the new image.

```js
  public image: string;

  constructor(
    private readonly domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private readonly service: YourService
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.findvehicleDocumentsImage(owner, registrationNumber, fileType)
    .subscribe(image => {
      // I suppose you retrieve an URL, but it depends from your data
      this.image = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(image);    
     });
  }
```

#### Component A - HTML

```html
<img [src]="image" />
```

In this way, you are retrieving, sanitizing the image, and displaying it.

##### Bonus tip:

You should implement an interceptor for adding the token to each of your HTTP requests. You can get more information here: [Angular Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor)